# Why SOME users cannot update record through the browser?

Tags: asp.net, crud

We have a simple SQL Server database with an ASP.NET front end.

I can easily update a record from my browser.

Another person cannot: he edits the field and hits the "update" button, but the change is not propagated to the database. The old value remains. He is using Internet Explorer. I checked the database, and his change is not propagated. There is no error thrown.

He WAS able to edit in May. Today he can't. but I can.

I can even update it with the Google Chrome browser.

Any ideas why his browser can't update, but I can?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this same user have the same problem every time?

Comment: Just to confirm, issue is with the browser? i.e, Can you update with IE?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue, not a browser issue.

Comment: Run SQL Profiler on the server to confirm that the query / procedure is being called for that particular user.  If it is, and if the query looks well formed, permissions sounds like a definite possibility as suggested by Fosco.

Comment: Yes. I can update it with the Internet Explorer browser just fine today.

I have't changed any accounts or permissions, and he was able to edit in May.

I wonder if some sort of Microsoft Update needs to be applied to his browser. Although if Chrome works, it shouldn't be a Microsoft browser issue.

Comment: @Dave: he has the issue now every time. But he was able to edit in May.

Comment: I would have him clear his cache/temp internet files to ensure that his cache has not got corrupted.  Also, have you had him try on another browser other than IE?

Comment: @Tommy:  Thanks. We'll check his cache.  The company requires him to use IE and I don't think he's allowed to install anything else on his corporate PC.

Comment: If using IE upgrade to the latest stable version.

Comment: @user204433: did you get resolution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check thoroughly your stored procedures and application structure, it might not be a browser issue at all. There must be some permission or user level problem in application.

Comment: Aren't the update queries running under the ASP.NET anonymous account? Permission to see the page is limited by a login to get to the page.  But once on the page, the username is not relevant to the update query.